# Old SF novel with underground Moon civilization, water very precious

Tags: story-identification, novel, moon

Sometime in the 1960s I read a paperback SF novel with one or more Earthmen on the Moon.  There was a nonhuman Moon civilization living underground.  It may have been a dystopian society and water was very rare and precious.

And that is about all I remember.  It was an old science fiction novel from about 1900 to 1950, but an author I don't remember but might have remembered as a well known early science fiction writer.

I am sure it wasn't the underground Moon civilization in H.G. Wells' *The First Men in the Moon*, nor the culture inside the hollow Moon in Edgar Rice Burroughs' *The Moon Maid*, nor the deep cavern Moon civilization in Otis Adelbert Klein's *Maza of the Moon*.

Comment: Do you recall if the Earthmen were astronauts from Earth, or were they living in a permanent base on the Moon?

Comment: What do you remember of protagonists?

Comment: Could it be Edmond Hamilton's *The Other Side of the Moon*? https://archive.org/details/Science_Fiction_Adventure_Classics_07_1969-Winter/mode/2up

Comment: The Moon Is A Harsh Mistress by Heinlein? The Moon is a penal colony that fights Earth for independence. They mine for ice in the rock.

Comment: *The Moon is a Harsh Mistress* is from 1966 and would have been brand new when the OP read it. It certainly is not from before 1950.

Comment: I've been searching through my golden age collection and underground civilisations on the Moon are common trope. I think it's going to be hard to identify the novel unless you can think of some extra "key facts" to help us pin it down.

Comment: I wondered if it might be an Edmond Hamilton story since the *Jupiter invasion* story was one of his. Hamilton wrote four *underground civilisation on Moon* stories: *Moon Menace*, *The Other Side of the Moon*, *Liline, the Moon Girl* and *Outlaws of the Moon*. Do any of these ring a bell?